# jinja giving error on pillar variable with absolute folder path

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I got a pillar item which looks something like below:

```
 "fileabspath": [
"Z:\\customer\region\chicago"
]
```

And on my sls file, I am trying to access the "filepath" pillar value with the below:

```
{% set fileabspath = salt['pillar.get']('fileabspath', None) %}

customer:
  region.filepath:
    - name: '{{fileabspath}}'
```

As soon as job hits above last line, I get below error.

```
failed: while parsing a block mapping\n  in \"<unicode string>\", line 10, column 1\ndid not find expected key\n  in \"<unicode string>\"
```

Any advice how to fix the issue ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes if you're using that data format

```json
"fileabspath": [
  "Z:\\\\customer\\region\\chicago"
]
```